# What is this Sequelize SELECT statement doing?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

When you use `sequelize.sync()` Sequelize creates all your tables and there are a bunch of `CREATE TABLE` statements as you'd expect. But then there are also a bunch of `SELECT` statements like this:

```
SELECT 
i.relname AS name, 
ix.indisprimary AS primary, 
ix.indisunique AS unique, 
ix.indkey AS indkey, 
array_agg(a.attnum) AS column_indexes, 
array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, 
pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM 
pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a 
WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid 
AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid 
AND a.attrelid = t.oid 
AND t.relkind = 'r' 
AND t.relname = 'heros' 
GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey 
ORDER BY i.relname;
```

What the heck are these huge `SELECT` statements doing? BTW, using Postgres here.

If I run the query, this is the output.

[image]

Comment: have you  tried  to  execute this query ??? ..

Comment: @scaisEdge yes, and I don't understand the output of that either. Seems like it has something to do with the index, but it's just a select statement, so, is it doing anything to my DB? Is it just a check process?

Comment: I think you're missing the `FROM` part of the query. Either way, my guess is that it's trying to figure out what already exists in the database (e.g. tables, columns, keys, etc.) so that it can compare it against what needs to be in the database (i.e. your database definition) and figure out what needs to be added/changed/removed. `sync` implies "make the necessary changes so that the database and your definition match." If it just created tables it wouldn't really be a "sync" action would it?

Comment: @Glenn   .. the query just return the list of the indexes  .. with relkind ='r' and relname ='heros'  .

Comment: @scaisEdge Ok, I was just trying to figure out why Sequelize was doing this, and wanted to confirm that it wasn't actually making any changes to the db. But it seems like as Cully said, maybe it's just some routine where its confirming that the table was created properly.